# A question on the remainders of integer division

Tags: elementary-number-theory, education

This is a question on the remainders of integer division from my student.

**Notations**.
Let $p$ be a positive odd prime integer.
We write $r_{i,j}$ for the remainder of $i \times j \div p$.
Now for an integer $u \in \{1, 2, \dots, p-2\}$, we define
\begin{align*}
K_1 =&\{ i : 1 \le i \le p-2,\ r_{i,u}+u<p,\ r_{i,p-u-1} <u+1\}, \\
K_2 =&\{ i : 1 \le i \le p-2,\ r_{i,u}+u<p,\ r_{i,p-u-1} >u+1\}, \\
K_3 =&\{ i : 1 \le i \le p-2,\ r_{i,u}+u>p,\ r_{i,p-u-1} <u+1\}, \\
K_4 =&\{ i : 1 \le i \le p-2,\ r_{i,u}+u>p,\ r_{i,p-u-1} >u+1\}. 
\end{align*}
And for another $u' \in \{1, 2, \dots, p-2\}$, we can define $K_\nu'$ for $\nu=1,2,3,4$.

**Question**.
If $K_1 =K_1'$ and $K_4=K_4'$, then either $K_2=K_2'$ and $K_3=K_3'$, or $K_2=K_3'$ and $K_3=K_2'$.

**What I have done**.

**1**. 
With the help of computer, I checked the correctness of this question for $p<100$.

**2**. 
Still with the help of computer, I found that, at least for $p<100$, if $K_1 =K_1'$ and $K_4=K_4'$, then either $u \equiv u' \pmod{p}$ or $u+u' \equiv p-1 \pmod{p}$.
The first case corresponds to the result $K_2=K_2'$ and $K_3=K_3'$, and the second one corresponds to the result  $K_2=K_3'$ and $K_3=K_2'$.

**3**.
I observed the definitions of the $K_\nu$'s, and found some equivalent conditions.
Firstly, we have
\begin{align*}
r_{i,u}+u<p &\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad r_{i+1,u} =r_{i,u} +u,\\
r_{i,u}+u>p &\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad r_{i+1,u} =r_{i,u} +u-p,
\end{align*}
and similarly,
\begin{align*}
r_{i,p-u-1} <u+1 &\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad r_{i+1,p-u-1} =r_{i,p-u-1} +(p-u-1),\\
r_{i,p-u-1} >u+1 &\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad r_{i+1,p-u-1} =r_{i,p-u-1} +(p-u-1) -p.
\end{align*}

**4**.
Using the discussion in (3), we obtain
\begin{align*}
i \in K_1
&\;\Leftrightarrow\; r_{i,u}+r_{i,p-u-1}<p \text{ but } r_{i+1,u}+r_{i+1,p-u-1}>p, \\
i \in K_4
&\;\Leftrightarrow\; r_{i,u}+r_{i,p-u-1}>p \text{ but } r_{i+1,u}+r_{i+1,p-u-1}<p, \\
i \in K_2 \cup K_3
&\;\Leftrightarrow\; \text{both $r_{i,u}+r_{i,p-u-1}$ and $r_{i+1,u}+r_{i+1,p-u-1}$ are $<p$ or $>p$}.
\end{align*}

**5**.
Now by the result in (4), we can see that $K_1 =K_1'$ and $K_4=K_4'$ if and only if for every $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, p-1\}$, the signatures of $r_{i,u}+r_{i,p-u-1}-p$ and $r_{i,u'}+r_{i,p-u'-1}-p$ are the same (i.e., both positive or both negative).

**However**, I really do not know how to solve this question, so if you have any idea, please help me.
Thank you very much for your attention.

---

Any ideas or hints are welcome. Please.

Answer (score 1):

To continue with your argument: you have the property that 
$r_{i,u}+r_{i,p−u−1}−p$ and $r_{i,u′}+r_{i,p−u′−1}−p$ have the same sign for all $i$. This is equivalent to saying that 
$r_{i,u} - r_{i,u+1}$ and $r_{i,u'} - r_{i,u'+1}$ have the same sign for all $i$.
This difference is always $p-i$ or $-i$, so this means that
$$
r_{i,u} - r_{i,u+1} = r_{i,u'} - r_{i,u'+1}
$$
for all $i=1,2,\ldots,p-2$.

One can also argue that this means that for all $i$ the sum of fractional parts
$$
\{\frac{iu}p\}
+
\{\frac{i(u'+1)}p\}
+\{\frac{i(-u')}p\}
=1+\{\frac{i(u+1)}p\}.
$$
This becomes a statement that some toric cyclic singularity in dimension three is terminal. These have been classified. I believe that corollary 1.3 of 
"TERMINAL QUOTIENT SINGULARITIES IN DIMENSIONS THREE AND FOUR"
DAVID R. MORRISON AND GLENN STEVENS
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-090-01/S0002-9939-1984-0722406-4/S0002-9939-1984-0722406-4.pdf
should give you the desired statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your generous help.